# Android GPS manifest not OK

Tags: android, gps, android-manifest

I am going to implement the GPS  into one of my menu

XML , JAVA code is OK

but when running this application , I have seen the application has stopped unexpectedly

here is my Manifest..

```
<application 
android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
android:label="@string/app_name">
```

....
        
         
               
                 
      
   
         
         
    ....

```
</application>
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Comment: FINE_LOCATION will be enough, depends on your program

Comment: how about adding .. to the location , like ..

   <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
   Where should be added ? 

here is the activity for GPS 
      <activity android:name="com.easyTravel.tool_gpsMap.tool_gpsMap"></activity>

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

to access the GPS

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GPS, add the permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION as well.

Comment: I have used the debug mode  , under ActivityThread Perform Source not found.

I have also added FINE LOCATION UNDER ..

   <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">

before application